# Power Automate filter array of objects based on another array

Tags: power-automate

I have a power automate flow where I have an array of objects which contains email address as a filed. I have another array that just has email addresses. I want to filter array of objects based on the email present in the other array. I am a newbie to power automate and any help in solving this would be highly appreciated.

**Array of objects:**

```
[
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "a23f2019-2b33-41af-a741-7faedeed9e0f",
      "First Name": "John",
      "Last Name": "Wick",
      "Email Address": "John.Wick@abc.com",
      "Manager Email Address": "test@abc.com",
      "Manager First Name": "John",
      "Manager Last Name": "Wick"
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "6fc4cc1b-13e8-47c3-9fca-09872fe758ae",
      "First Name": "John2",
      "Last Name": "Wick2",
      "Email Address": "John.Wick2@abc.com",
      "Manager Email Address": "test2@abc.com",
      "Manager First Name": "John2",
      "Manager Last Name": "Wick2"
    }
  ]
```

**Array of email addresses:**

```
  [
    "a@abc.com",
    "b@abc.com",
    "c@abc.com",
    "test@abc.com"
  ]
```

So, the result I am looking for is an array of objects that contains the matching object (in this case):

```
[
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "a23f2019-2b33-41af-a741-7faedeed9e0f",
      "First Name": "John",
      "Last Name": "Wick",
      "Email Address": "John.Wick@abc.com",
      "Manager Email Address": "test@abc.com",
      "Manager First Name": "Test",
      "Manager Last Name": "Surname"
    }
]
```

Comment: You open to a third party connector?

Comment: @Skin sure. I can try it out.

Comment: I'll give you an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve it quite easily using the **Advanced Data Operations** connector.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/

However, the most annoying part about the dataset you've provided is that the email addresses used to filter the main array is more of a primitive type array where as it needs to be an object based array.

Either way, I'll explain the flow I have tested with.

[image: Flow]

#### Step 1/2.

Both of these steps are merely variables of type **Array** that hold the values you specified in your question, noting that the `@` at the start of the first properties have been removed because PA doesn't like them.

#### Step 3.

This is a very small C# script that turns your primitive array into an object array.

[image: C# Script]

**Script**

```
var result = new List<ReturnData>();

foreach (var item in parameters.ArrayToTransform)
  result.Add(new ReturnData() { EmailAddress = item });

return result;
```

**Class Definitions**

```
public class ReturnData
{
    [JsonProperty("Manager Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Parameters**

```
{
  "ArrayToTransform": @{variables('Email Address Array')}
}
```

This is the resulting output and it's this structure that we need for the final step ...

```
{
  "returnValue": [
    {
      "Manager Email Address": "a@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "Manager Email Address": "b@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "Manager Email Address": "c@abc.com"
    },
    {
      "Manager Email Address": "test@abc.com"
    }
  ],
  "log": []
}
```

#### Step 4.

This step is a little superfluous but am doing it anyway.  I'm basically taking the output from the C# Script operation and setting the `Email Address Array` value with it.

[image: Set Variable]

**Expression =** `outputs('C#_Script_Execute')?['body']['returnValue']`

#### Step 5.

Now with the two datasets, you can perform an inner join and remove the data that doesn't match up to a supplied email address.

[image: Join]

Take note, you want to join on the `Manager Email Address` (I made an assumption here given it matches to an email in the list) and the fields you want to return are only those from the `Array To Filter` dataset.

**Join Fields =** `[ "Manager Email Address" ]`

**Fields =** `[ "+FieldName(ArrayToFilter.%)" ]`

#### Result

Only the one result is returned because that's the only one that married up to an entry in the email addresses list.

```
[
  {
    "odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "a23f2019-2b33-41af-a741-7faedeed9e0f",
    "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Wick",
    "Email Address": "John.Wick@abc.com",
    "Manager Email Address": "test@abc.com",
    "Manager First Name": "John",
    "Manager Last Name": "Wick"
  }
]
```

[image: Join Result]